# Magento add to cart button direct to magento/index.php/checkout/cart/ page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using shopper theme for my magento online shop. I am developing it on Xampp. Almost all things are complete, but one new problem is there.

> when i click on the add to cart button it supposed to use a ajax/js
>   and add the product to the bag. but it takes me to this page
>   magento/index.php/checkout/cart

Can any one tell me how can I stay on the respected page and can add products to cart.

Comment: there's an option in the admin config for enabling Add to cart without redirect to the cart page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

Admin -> System -> Config -> (Sales) Checkout -> Shopping Cart

Set 'After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart' = NO